# i can't figure out which component of the spring is doing this

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

10.5. AuthenticationManager
AuthenticationManager is the API that defines how Spring Security’s Filters perform authentication. The Authentication that is returned is then set on the SecurityContextHolder by the controller (i.e. Spring Security’s Filterss) that invoked the AuthenticationManager. If you are not integrating with Spring Security’s Filterss you can set the SecurityContextHolder directly and are not required to use an AuthenticationManager.

i can't figure out which component of the spring is doing this-  "SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication()"

1. The Authentication that is returned is then set on the SecurityContextHolder by the controller (i.e. Spring Security’s Filterss) that invoked the AuthenticationManager.

Comment: it is a series of filters, debug please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter#successfulAuthentication

```
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: "
                    + authResult);
        }

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);

        rememberMeServices.loginSuccess(request, response, authResult);

        // Fire event
        if (this.eventPublisher != null) {
            eventPublisher.publishEvent(new InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent(
                    authResult, this.getClass()));
        }

        successHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authResult);
    }
```